# JS Loop through array based on key values and add values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following object inside an array:-

```
[
 {"score": 5, "question": 0, "weight": 2},
 {"score": 4, "question": 1, "weight": 2},
 {"score": 3, "question": 0, "weight": 4},
 {"score": 4, "question": 1, "weight": 4},
 {"score": 2, "question": 2, "weight": 4},
 {"score": 8, "question": 0, "weight": 2}
]
```

I am trying to loop through the array so I have the following output, so I am able to run some math against the results:-

```
[
  [
    {"score": 5, "question": 0, "weight": 2},
    {"score": 4, "question": 1, "weight": 2}
  ],
  [
    {"score": 3, "question": 0, "weight": 4},
    {"score": 4, "question": 1, "weight": 4},
    {"score": 2, "question": 2, "weight": 4}
  ],
  [
    {"score": 8, "question": 0, "weight": 2}
  ]
];
```

Is there a dynamic way I am able to get array1 to look like array2?

I am using flat JS for this please no jQuery answers.

Thanks in advance.

** Note **

Sometimes each section will have more or less values, this is why I require it to be dynamic.

Comment: @Slai, no, because it should group same weights, not collect some counts.

Comment: It's not grouping by weights as they could all be group 2 for example. It needs to loop through the questions and if it resets back to 0 start a new array inside the larger array. The main identifier is the question id.

Comment: please add your attempt.

Comment: @TonyHensler _it should group same weights_ then why group1 and group3 are different as for both group weight is 2.

Comment: @yajiv it's splitting by sequences that start with `"question": 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `reduce()` method you just need to keep track of current index for final array.

```js
const data =[
  {score: 5, question: 0, weight: 2},
  {score: 4, question: 1, weight: 2},
  {score: 3, question: 0, weight: 4},
  {score: 4, question: 1, weight: 4},
  {score: 2, question: 2, weight: 4},
  {score: 8, question: 0, weight: 2}
]

const result = data.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  if(i == 0) r = {values: [], counter: 0}
  if(e.question == 0 && i != 0) r.counter++
  if(!r.values[r.counter]) r.values[r.counter] = [e]
  else r.values[r.counter].push(e)
  return r;
}, {}).values

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check `weight` and if different, then take a new group.

```js
var data = [{ score: 5, question: 0, weight: 2 }, { score: 4, question: 1, weight: 2 }, { score: 3, question: 0, weight: 4 }, { score: 4, question: 1, weight: 4 }, { score: 2, question: 2, weight: 4 }, { score: 8, question: 0, weight: 2 }],
    grouped = data.reduce(function (r, o, i, a) {
        if ((a[i - 1] || {}).weight !== o.weight) {
            r.push([]);
        }
        r[r.length - 1].push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to convert the 1st to the 2nd array. Whenever the current object weight doesn't match `lastWeight`, add another subarray. Always push the current item to the last subarray:

```js
const arr = [
  {score: 5, question: 0, weight: 2},
  {score: 4, question: 1, weight: 2},
  {score: 3, question: 0, weight: 4},
  {score: 4, question: 1, weight: 4},
  {score: 2, question: 2, weight: 4},
  {score: 8, question: 0, weight: 2}
];

let lastWeight = null;
const result = arr.reduce((r, o) => {
  if(lastWeight === null || o.weight !== lastWeight) {
    lastWeight = o.weight;
    r.push([]);
  }
  r[r.length - 1].push(o);
  
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var oldA = [
 {"score": 5, "question": 0, "weight": 2},
 {"score": 4, "question": 1, "weight": 2},
 {"score": 3, "question": 0, "weight": 4},
 {"score": 4, "question": 1, "weight": 4},
 {"score": 2, "question": 2, "weight": 4},
 {"score": 8, "question": 0, "weight": 2}
];

var newA = [];
var prevW = 0;
var prevA;

for (var i = 0; i < oldA.length; i++) {
  if (oldA[i].weight != prevW) {
    prevA = [];
    newA.push(prevA);
    prevW = oldA[i].weight;
  }
  prevA.push(oldA[i]);
}

console.log(newA);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to group your array. Check if the value of `question` is `0` then push a new array and add the object to it.

```js
var data = [ {"score": 5, "question": 0, "weight": 2}, {"score": 4, "question": 1, "weight": 2}, {"score": 3, "question": 0, "weight": 4}, {"score": 4, "question": 1, "weight": 4}, {"score": 2, "question": 2, "weight": 4}, {"score": 8, "question": 0, "weight": 2}],
    result = data.reduce((r,o) => {
      if(o.question == 0)
        r.push([]);
      r[r.length - 1].push(o);
      return r;
    },[]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let scores = [
 {"score": 5, "question": 0, "weight": 2},
 {"score": 4, "question": 1, "weight": 2},
 {"score": 3, "question": 0, "weight": 4},
 {"score": 4, "question": 1, "weight": 4},
 {"score": 2, "question": 2, "weight": 4},
 {"score": 8, "question": 0, "weight": 2}
]

let groupedScores = [], group = [];

scores.forEach((entry) => {
  if(entry.question === 0) { 
    if (group.length) { 
      groupedScores.push(group); 
    }
    group = []; 
  }
  group.push(entry);
})
groupedScores.push(group)

console.log(groupedScores)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit simplified if splitting by just `question: 0` :

```js
data = [ { score: 5, question: 0, weight: 2 }, { score: 4, question: 1, weight: 2 },
         { score: 3, question: 0, weight: 4 }, { score: 4, question: 1, weight: 4 },
         { score: 2, question: 2, weight: 4 }, { score: 8, question: 0, weight: 2 } ]

result = data.reduce((r, v) => (v.question ? r[r.length-1].push(v) : r.push([v]), r), [])

console.log( result )
```